# Flutter webView - how send loadUrl to webView Screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

I have an app.dart with Drawer() and widget with dynamically changed webview from 2nd screen. I'm not able to change url in webview clicking on Drawer items.
Is it possible to somehow use loadURL from drawer and change url in webview?

app.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  
  body:  Center(
    child: HeadlessInAppWebViewExampleScreen(page: page),
  ),
   drawer: Drawer(
    child: Container(

    color: Colors.black,
    child: ListView(
      // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
      children: [
    
        ListTile(
            title: Text("Load url", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              page = '/newSite';
             });
           },
       
      ],
    ),
  ),
  ),
);}
```

This is the 2nd screen which contains inappwebview, but once loaded url is not changing.
I also trie to add  in Widget build:

**webViewController?.loadUrl(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: url));**

but if setState for progress is not commented, webview falls into loop

HeadlessInAppWebViewExample.dart

```
class HeadlessInAppWebViewExampleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String page;
  
  const HeadlessInAppWebViewExampleScreen({Key key, this.page}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HeadlessInAppWebViewExampleScreenState createState() =>
      new _HeadlessInAppWebViewExampleScreenState();
}

class _HeadlessInAppWebViewExampleScreenState
    extends State<HeadlessInAppWebViewExampleScreen> {
  InAppWebViewController webViewController;

  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();
   InAppWebViewSettings settings = InAppWebViewSettings(
      useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      iframeAllow: "camera; microphone",
      iframeAllowFullscreen: true
  );
   String url = "";

  double progress = 0;
  final urlController = TextEditingController();
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

   }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    
    var url = WebUri("https://google.com");


      return Scaffold(

          body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[

                Expanded(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [

                      InAppWebView(
                        key: webViewKey,
                        initialUrlRequest:
                        URLRequest(url: url),
                        initialSettings: settings,
                        onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                          webViewController = controller;
                        },
                       

                        onPermissionRequest: (controller, request) async {
                          return PermissionResponse(
                              resources: request.resources,
                              action: PermissionResponseAction.GRANT);
                        },
                        shouldOverrideUrlLoading:
                            (controller, navigationAction) async {
                          var uri = navigationAction.request.url;

                          if (![
                            "http",
                            "https",
                            "file",
                            "chrome",
                            "data",
                            "javascript",
                            "about"
                          ].contains(uri.scheme)) {
                            if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
                              // Launch the App
                              await launchUrl(
                                uri,
                              );
                              // and cancel the request
                              return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                            }
                          }

                          return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                        },
                        onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
                         },
                        onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                         },
                        onReceivedError: (controller, request, error) {
                        },
                        onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                          // if (progress == 100) {
                          // }
                          // setState(() {
                          //   this.progress = progress / 100;
                          // });
                        },
                        onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                          // setState(() {
                          // });
                        },
                        onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
                          print(consoleMessage);
                        },
                      ),
                      Container()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ])));
    }
  }
```

Comment: you are already using a scaffold, which has a drawer property, why have the drawer live in the same class so that you dont have to worry about passing between classes, and would instead just setState() to update the url. i can provide code if needed.

Comment: i got your point, but i dont want to have appbar in webview screen. I just want to load webview in App()

Comment: i created webview function in app.dart so i can set loadURL from Drawer()